# Java private method wrapping

Tags: java, design-patterns, methods, private

I have seen the following pattern used in several frameworks, where a private method is wrapped in a public method:

```
public Object method_public()
{
   return method_private();
}


private Object method_private()
{
   return Object;
}
```

What is this pattern called and when should it be used?

Comment: Please link to an example where you've seen this used.

Comment: There are many reasonable scenarios where something like this makes sense. I'm not aware of any particular name for this (not every line of code is a "pattern").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Delegation pattern`. But in very strange manner.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern